# How can i import scss files and images in stories of storybook in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, sass, storybook

I have a simple component as you can see here, which imports an image via `src="@/assets/images/logo.png"` using `@ for addressing` :

```
<template>
  <div class="loading_container">
    <img
      class="loading_logo"
      src="@/assets/images/logo.png"
      alt="company logo"
    />
    <div class="loading_box">
      <div class="loading_dot"></div>
      <div class="loading_dot"></div>
      <div class="loading_dot"></div>
      <div class="loading_dot"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "@vue/composition-api";
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Loading"
});
</script>
```

And this is my story, which i imported here but it seems to not working :

```
import Loading from "../src/views/components/loading/Loading";
import  "../src/assets/styles/components/_Loading.scss";
export default {
  title: "Loading"
};

export const normalLoading = () => ({
  components: { Loading },
  template: "<Loading></Loading>",
});
```

When I use npm run storybook, it will show two errors, one for each one of the above issues. how should I fix these issues?

**update**

The error for image is :

```
    ERROR in ./src/views/components/loading/Loading.vue?vue&type=template&id=1f4267ea& (./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js??vue-loader-options!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/components/loading/Loading.vue?vue&type=template&id=1f4267ea&)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/assets/images/logo.png' in 'C:\Projects\my_github\vuejs-persian-chat-scaffold\src\views\components\loading'
 @ ./src/views/components/loading/Loading.vue?vue&type=template&id=1f4267ea& (./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js??vue-loader-options!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/components/loading/Loading.vue?vue&type=template&id=1f4267ea&) 15:22-57
 @ ./src/views/components/loading/Loading.vue?vue&type=template&id=1f4267ea&
 @ ./src/views/components/loading/Loading.vue
 @ ./stories/loading.stories.js
 @ ./stories sync ^\.\/(?:(?:(?!\.)(?:(?:(?!(?:|[\\/])\.).)*?)[\\/])?(?!\.)(?=.)[^\\/]*?\.stories\.js[\\/]?)$
 @ ./.storybook/generated-entry.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./.storybook/generated-entry.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=true
```

and here is my `./storybook/webpack.config.js` file which is working on addressing like `import  "../src/assets/styles/components/_Loading.scss";` but i want to use `@/` for addressing:

```
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = function({ config }) {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, "../")
  });
  config.plugins.push(new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: "[name].css" }));

  return config;
};
```

Since it seems this problem is widespread, I asked on [storybook's GitHub](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/11117) and it seems they need to add compatibility mode for this.

Comment: What are the errors?

I haven't used storybook before, but you might need to add an scss loader to your project.
https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/

Comment: The img resolving error only shows when you use the `@` alias? I don't see this in your webpack config. If you are using `vue-cli` you can inpect the merged webpack config with `vue inspect --rules` and `vue inspect --rule <image/scss>`

Comment: It doesn't work at all, but if use       `src="/src/assets/images/logo.png"` and then run storybook using `"storybook": "start-storybook -s ./ -p 6006"`, it will be run and load correctly, but it is not what I want here. I just want to use @ to work with that.

Comment: There are actually a lot of issues on github about `storybook.js` and other frameworks using webpack interfering with each other. Try to find a solution in those comments.
https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/3339
https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/44

google for more discussions: `storybook js webpack alias "@"`

Comment: I did those solutions but none of them worked here. it would be great if there was a working example of this issue.

Comment: Also check out these examples: https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/custom-webpack-config/#examples

https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/custom-webpack-config/#using-your-existing-config

"Note that Storybook has a completely separate webpack config for its own UI (also referred to as the “manager”), so the customizations you make only applies to the rendering of your stories"

Comment: How about running `start-storybook -s ./src/assets/` and referring to the images like this? `src="images/logo.png"`

`
https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/cli-options/#for-start-storybook

Comment: Other thing comes in mind that think aliasing `@` to `src` is a `vue` thing, so you might try to add this alias somewhere in your `storybook` webpack config.

Comment: `start-storybook -s ./src/assets/`, method is working, but it is not what we wanted and need the whole project tp change. i'm already struggling with aliases `  config.resolve = {
    alias: {
      "@": path.join(__dirname, "/src")
    },
    extensions: [".vue", ".js", ".jsx", ".css", ".png", ".jpg", ".gif", ".jpeg"]
  };`

Comment: Yea, I'm not familiar with webpack configs and how they merge together. Vue cli makes this scaffolding for me usually, and I stick with the defaults. You might have later problem in your build or deployment too, if the paths don't resolve properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked the question on storybook's github, and I got an answer to use vue-cli to fix the problem.

So, First I stashed all changes which have been made by following the instructions of 
 https://storybook.js.org/docs/guides/guide-vue/ .

Then I've re-installed storybook via using `vue add storybook` ( https://github.com/storybookjs/vue-cli-plugin-storybook ) which creates a folder that contains webpack configs from vue-cli, which means you don't need to have any special webpack section in storybook config folder. the @ problem has been solved and every thing is fine

```
<img
  class="loading_logo"
  src="@/assets/images/logo.png"
  alt="company logo"
/>
```

But still there was one error for addressing assets in `.scss` `url()` like content:

```
url("assets/images/tick.svg");
```

I fixed it by using relative addressing using `~@` together like below:

```
content: url("~@/assets/images/tick.svg");
```

the working example is here:

https://github.com/SeyyedKhandon/vuejs-persian-chat-scaffold